# Why is the object value not changing?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to pull a Post object from my MongoDB. This Post has an author field, which is an ObjectID referencing who authored the blog post. Once I fetch the blog post, I want to fetch the Author's username and replace the ID in the post object before sending it out to as a response to clients.

When running the code, the correct Post shows when I log it, and the correct Username is shown when it is fetched, but I can never modify the object itself.

```
BlogController.getPost(id, (error, result) => {
    if (error) res.send({success:false, message:error})
    else {
        var post = result
        AuthController.getUserByID(post.author, (error, resultNested) => {
            if (error) res.send({success:false, message:error})
            else {
                post.author = resultNested.username
                console.log(post)
                console.log(resultNested)
                res.send({success:true, message:post})
            }
        }) 
    }
})
```

I would include the console log outputs to show you the structure of the objects and that the values I am trying to modify xist, but the new StackOverflow UI makes inputting code even more of a pain in the ass than the past. Somehow...

I expect for the `post` object to have it's `author`field modified, but the author field remains an ObjectID.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the name of the author in the post model as a start. MongoDB is referred to as a 'Document Based' DB and I therefore like to think of each record in a collection as a standalone 'document'.

I can understand the logic of the relational model you are trying to implement, but since MongoDB stores data in JSON format - one could argue that there is some room for redundancy.

I would recommend...

```
post{
 author : string;
 .
 .
 .
 relUser : string;
}
```

Where the relUser field will be the id of the user that posted the blog entry and we store the author/username in the author field. In this way you simplify the number of calls you need to make, by getting more info per single call.

Comment: Initially I decided to store the ID instead of the Username or Email, as it seemed good design, however upon further research, there doesn't seem to be performance gains by looking up by ID vs any other field.

Comment: Correct, but by saving your author's name *directly at the time of creation* of the post there will be no need for a lookup when querying for the post (as above). You could simply query on the relUser field and the author name would already be in the instance of the post object without having to convert the userId to the name.

Comment: Yes that's true. I'll probably be replacing all instances of ID fetching then, I use it a few times throughout the program when referencing other collections.

Comment: However, I am still curious, bad design or not, why the code in my OP doesn't actually modify any values...

Comment: Looking at the logic it does seem correct. Why don't you try creating a new instance of the post object and setting that equal to the post instance being used in the query and modifying the new instance author field?

It could be that something is still pointing to the original value and since said value is being used in the enclosing function it may be out of scope....